# How to run multiple servers on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, apache-http-server, webserver, node.js

I have the capability to SSH into a Linux machine hosted on a server. Is there a possibility that I can install multiple servers on the same machine - say Apache and NodeJS? Is there a tool/app that I can install on that machine to manage multiple servers? Also, the linux machine has an ip address associated with it. Can I create a sub-domain where I can essentially cater to multiple applications and re-direct to the server I need?

Comment: docker, lxc, etc.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks for the info. Are there any tutorials? I'm confused as to how 2 servers can share the same ip.